# CouchDB inner join by document field?

Tags: couchdb

I have a question, i have 2 kind of documents, one of them is like this:

```
{
  "type": "PageType",
  "filename": "demo"
  "content": "zzz"
}
```

and another one like this:

```
{
  "type": "PageCommentType",
  "refFilename": "demo"
  "content": "some comment content"
}
```

i need to emit document that contains .comments field which is array of PageCommentType documents that i link on condition PageType document filename == PageCommentType document refFilename fields.

```
{
  "filename": "demo",
  "comments": [{}, {}, {}]
}
```

Anyone has any suggestions on how to implement it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You need **view collation**. Emit both within the same view, using the `filename` as the key and a type identifier to discriminate between comments and the original content:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.type == "PageType") emit([doc.filename,0],doc.content);
  if (doc.type == "PageCommentType") emit[doc.refFilename,1],doc.content);
}
```

When looking for the document `demo` and its comments, run a query with `startkey=["demo",0]` and `endkey=["demo",1]`: you will get the page content followed by all the comments.

Once you have all the **data** you want, but it's not in the right **format**, you are almost done. Simply write a `_list` function to read all the rows and output the final JSON document with the structure/schema that you need.

Comment: Did you mean `doc.comments` for the second `emit`?

Comment: this two rows result i managed, but it's not what im looking for. i wanted to have aggregated document that has comments attribute which is array of documents emitted of type PageCommentType... in earlier versions of CouchDb as i recall there was some way to call map within map function and somehow wrap it, but i just can't figure out how it works now...

Comment: Sometimes if I hear "aggregated," that is a clue to **reduce** from the map/reduce views. Unfortunately, reducing is not going to work here because you are *accumulating* data rather than *reducing* it. (In other words, you'll get an error that the reduce size is too big.) I will amend Victor's answer with some ideas.

Comment: Aggregation not necessary means what you had in mind, it's about collecting data and spitting it in certain format, this is why i was specific in my question on how i want to see my data, so Vistor's answer is not fitting here, because what he suggests will spit resultset like   {"total_rows":4,"offset":0,"rows":[]} where rows array will have first element as my document of PageType and rest of the array items will be PageCommentType -- this is too simple, totally not what i'm looking for...

Comment: @Skitsanos: in that case, use a `_list` function as suggested by jhs' edit to transform the resultset into a more appropriate format.