# How can I use my sql knowledge with Cloudant/CouchDB?

Tags: sql, couchdb, cloudant, cookbook, recipe

Some developers who have a good knowledge of querying SQL databases struggle to implement the equivalent query patterns in Cloudant/CouchDB.

How can these developers translate their SQL knowledge to Cloudant/CouchDB?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This community wiki page provides links to some SQL patterns showing how they may be implemented in Cloudant.

As this is a community wiki feel free to add new Q&A links here.

### General database queries

- [Joining two documents by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248307/couchdb-join-two-documents-using-key)
- [How do I do the SQL equivalent of “DISTINCT” in CouchDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534376/how-do-i-do-the-sql-equivalent-of-distinct-in-couchdb)
- [How do I do a triple join in CouchDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684590/triple-join-in-couchdb)
- [Inner joining by document field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787711/couchdb-inner-join-by-document-field?rq=1)
- [How do I do subqueries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293171/couchdb-views-joins-and-subqueries?rq=1)
- [How to do a one-to-many join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033443/best-way-to-do-one-to-many-join-in-couchdb)
- [How to do many-to-many joins?](http://danielwertheim.se/couchdb-many-to-many-relations/)
- [multiple WHERE and OR clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28345751/how-to-create-a-view-in-couchdb-with-multiple-where-and-or-clauses)
- [WHERE ...  IN query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763430/performing-a-where-in-query-in-couchdb)
- [WHERE ... NOT IN query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413953/couchdb-equivalent-of-sql-not-in)
- [Performing queries across databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961337/joins-between-different-databases-in-couchdb)
- [Can I do transactions and locks in CouchDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299723/can-i-do-transactions-and-locks-in-couchdb)
- [Cloudant SQL Join cookbook](https://cloudant.com/blog/sql-joins/)
- Add your new Q&A links here ...

### Aggregate database queries

- [COUNT(*) aggregate function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586585/what-is-the-couchdb-equivalent-of-the-sql-count-aggregate-function?rq=1)
- [SUM * GROUP BY queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511810/couchdb-view-equivalent-of-sum-group-by?rq=1)
- Add your new  Q&A links here ...

### Full text queries (lucene) - Cloudant only

- Add your new  Q&A links here ...

### See also

- [View cookbook for SQL jockeys](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/cookbook.html)