# How to create a view in CouchDB with multiple WHERE and OR clauses

Tags: couchdb

How would I creat a view equivalent to a SQL query like this?

**SELECT * FROM bucket WHERE (uid='$uid' AND accepted='Y') OR (uid='$uid' AND authorid='$logginid')**

My data is stored this way:

```
{
"id": 9476183,
"authorid": 85490,
"content": "some text here",
"uid": 41,
"accepted": "Y",
"time": "2014-12-09 10:44:01",
"type": "testimonial"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.accepted == 'Y') {
        emit(doc.uid, null);
    }
    emit([doc.uid, doc.authorid], null);
}
```

One request is enough. You can tap view written by @Simon (reproduced above) using POST with param `keys:[[uid, authorid], uid]`.

See http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/ddoc/views.html#post--db-_design-ddoc-_view-view for mode details.

Answer (score 0):

A view could look like this:

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.accepted == 'Y') {
        emit(doc.uid, null);
    }
    emit([doc.uid, doc.authorid], null);
}
```

You would query it with `key=$uid` first. If there is no match, you would query it with `key=[$uid,$loginid]`.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the try, but this way it won't work in my case. I will always pass for example this value startkey=[uid,authorid]  - So this line of code emit(doc.uid, null);  is not expecting to get an array of itens.

Comment: It it was possible to just ignore the $loginid value if accepted.Y it would work.

Comment: It thing it should work replacing third line by this one:
emit([doc.uid],null);  than it will return results whenever key has one or two values, but if I put key=[uid,logginid] it won't return the documents with accepted=Y

Comment: I was suggesting you do *two distinct queries*. I'm sure there is a better way but that's a start.