# Generate query results based on tags in PouchDB

Tags: angularjs, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm new to NoSQL but have decided to use PouchDB for an Angular Application I am creating.

There are going to be a series of questions (about 1000 in total) which each have their own tags. Each object shouldn't have more that 6 or 7 tags. Example data is:

```
{
    "text": "Question?",
    "answers": [
        { "text": "Yes", "correct": true },
        { "text": "No", "correct": false }
    ],
    "tags": ["tag1", "tag3"]
},
{
    "text": "Question?",
    "answers": [
        { "text": "Yes","correct": true },
        { "text": "No", "correct": false }
    ],
    "tags": ["tag2", "tag3"]
}
```

I'm at a total loss on how I can query the db in order to retrieve only questions that have "tag2" or questions that have "tag1" and "tag3".

I came across the question found at [How to query PouchDB with SQL-like operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28806853/how-to-query-pouchdb-with-sql-like-operators) but can't seem to wrap my head around how it works. I tried to modify it based on my data and I always get 0 results when querying the database.

I guess my biggest struggle is comparing it to SQL when it isn't. Does anyone know how I can go about creating a query based on specific tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, you create a [map/reduce query](http://pouchdb.com/guides/queries.html) like this:

```
// document that tells PouchDB/CouchDB
// to build up an index on tags
var ddoc = {
  _id: '_design/my_index',
  views: {
    my_index: {
      map: function (doc) {
        doc.tags.forEach(function (tag) {
          emit(tag);
        });
      }.toString()
    }
  }
};
// save it
pouch.put(ddoc).then(function () {
  // success!
}).catch(console.log.bind(console));
```

Then you query it:

```
pouch.query('my_index', {key: myTag, include_docs: true}).then(function (res) {
  // got a result
}).catch(console.log.bind(console));
```

If you want to find multiple tags, you can just `keys` instead of `key`.

BTW this will be easier in the future when I add `$elemMatch` and `$in` to [pouchdb-find](http://nolanlawson.github.io/pouchdb-find/).

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer this. My query is successful but I still am getting 0 rows returned. my query looks like `db.query('my_index', { key: '203', include_docs: true }).then` and have confirmed that at least one of the records has a tag of 203. What am I missing?

Comment: perhaps it has to do with the view not being generated correctly. when I use the fauxton UI to create the view the index is empty but when I do a simple emit doc._id I get all of the records outputted. ::edit:: ah that was it, once I removed the .toString in fauxton i was able to get results returned. How can I condense the list when searching on multiple keys? right now I have duplicates. Is there a way to say ok, only records with both tags present?

Comment: Your simplified example allowed me to better understand the map function. After that understanding I was able to get the example referenced above working to my needs. I look forward to seeing pouchdb-find updated with $elemMatch and $in. is there a roadmap for that?

Comment: For records with both tags, you would need to do two separate queries and then join the results (unfortunately). As for pouchdb-find, I don't have a roadmap, but I work on it when I have time. :)

Comment: thanks @nlawson. I have one more question, is there a way to stack views? lets say I have a categories and tags. Can I do a query to select a single category and then piggyback another view to query a specific tag within that category?

Comment: No, you would need to have both the category and the tag inside of a single view, e.g. `emit([doc.category, doc.tag])`

Comment: I know this is close to two years old but I was wondering if pouchdb-find now makes this easier/more robust? I was looking at the documentation and couldn't quite figure it out.