# How to do "Not Equals" in couchdb?

Tags: couchdb

Folks, I was wondering what is the best way to model document and/or map functions that allows me "Not Equals" queries.

For example, my documents are:

```
1. { name : 'George' }
2. { name : 'Carlin' }
```

I want to trigger a query that returns every documents where name not equals 'John'.

- Note: I don't have all possible names before hand. So the parameters in query can be any random text like 'John' in my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: there is no easy solution.

You have four options:

- sending a multi range query
- filter the view response with a server-side list function
- using a CouchDB plugin
- use the mango query language

**sending a multi range query**

You can request the view with two ranges defined by startkey and endkey. You have to choose the range so, that the key `John` is not requested.

Unfortunately you have to find the commit request that somewhere exists and compile your CouchDB with it. Its not included in the official source.

**filter the view response with a server-side list function**

Its not recommended but you can use a list function and ignore the row with the key `John` in your response. Its like you will do it with a JavaScript array.

**using a CouchDB plugin**

Create an additional index with e.g. couchdb-lucene. The lucene server has such query capabilities.

**use the "mango" query language**

Its included in the CouchDB 2.0 developer preview. Not ready for production but will be definitely included in the stable release.