# Migration guide to move from SQL to CouchDB

Tags: sql, nosql, couchdb

My question: Would you have some web pages (or tutorial) to point me to, that would focus on migrating guide from SQL to NoSQL, especially for 1-N relationship modelling?

A bit more on my needs:

I have to develop a CouchDB-based application in which I have several 1-N relationships between about 10 different types of objects.

The application needs to do many different queries to filter and sort the data based on fields that belong to the several types of objects. It would be so easy to do in SQL, but with CouchDB I fail.

I know, things have to be thought differently between SQL and NoSQL, but despite all the documents/forums/etc. I could read, I could find no guidelines to change my way of thinking and to be a good NoSQL man, and write my queries.

I have also tried the Mango queries which were looking somehow more powerful than map/reduce in some cases, so this in option of interest for me too.

Many thanks!

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339910/how-can-i-use-my-sql-knowledge-with-cloudant-couchdb/28339911#28339911) it might help.

Comment: Can you tell us the reason for moving from a SQL database to NoSQL one?  E.g. what are the expected benefits once you've made the move?

Comment: @EricClack: I need to develop a mobile app which syncs its data with a server database, and which is able to work offline with some data. So the CouchDB replication features, along with PouchDB appears to be the only solution for that. I have found no way to have sync+offline features with a SQL database (unfortunately). However if you know something for that please let me know!